# Install pfSense using serial console

Tags: pfsense

I want to install pfSense with the ISO installer but only have a serial console available.

How do I tell the installer to use the serial console instead of VGA?

Answer (score 4):

After booting to the loader screen, press <kbd>7</kbd> to escape to the loader prompt.

Then type:

```
set comconsole_speed=115200
set console=comconsole
boot
```

---

N.B.: currently on the pfSense 2.0.1 installer typing `set console=comconsole` reverts the speed to 9600 even if it's set otherwise.